# Error: APK has not been signed with the upload certificate. [403] - VS2019 Archive Manager

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Recently I contacted Google Support to have my Upload Certificate/Keystore reset for my application. Now when I'm trying to update my app which was used with the original key, I get the error **"An error occur uploading 'xxxxx.apk': APK has not been signed with the upload certificate. [403]APK has not been signed with the upload certificate. [403]"**.

This is done using the built-in **Archive Manager** inside Visual Studio 2019 for Xamarin. And all I'm doing is following the steps for a Google Play distribution.

The keystore used is the same one as the one used to generate my new .pem-file which was sent to google in order to reset the certficate.

Below is a print of the keystore information. This key was generated by using the follwing cmd

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
```

And the .pem was generated with

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

The MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 hashes are the same as the **Upload certificate** hashes on Google Play Console, however I feel like there's something missing? I just don't know what.

Any idea on how to resolve this error would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How do you sign your APK?

Comment: @Pierre Just following the steps inside Archive Manager in VS2019. It does all the signing, uploading etc for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VS2019 unfortunately. When you reset your key, it takes 48 hours to take effect. Have you waited for that time?

Comment: @Pierre The reset was due to be done 4th of August :/

Comment: And you updated your keystore in VS in all the places? Maybe cleared the cache or something? Sorry I'm out of ideas. Try to look at the APK that is uploaded by VS and check what certificate it is signed with (using keytool, or apksigner) to confirm its effectively signed with the right key before being uploaded to the Play Console.